# NullPointerException at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removeRule(ReteooBuilder.java:252)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, drools

I am using drools expert 5.4.0.Final, for a scenario where I am dynamically creating rule DRL, adding it to knowledgebase and firing the rule. 
I am trying to disable/enable rule at a later point (after adding the DRL). To achieve this, I am trying to remove the rule from knowledge base for disabling, like so:

```
    KnowledgeBase sessionBase = kSession.getKnowledgeBase();
    sessionBase.removeRule(RULE_PACKAGE_NAME, name);
```

This works fine for the first time.

Then, I enable the rule by adding the DRL again, like so:

```
    kBuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(rule.toDrl().getBytes()),
                ResourceType.DRL);
    kBase.addKnowledgePackages(kBuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
```

Then, when I disable it again, I get the following exception:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removeRule(ReteooBuilder.java:259)
at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.removeRule(ReteooRuleBase.java:459)
at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.removeRule(AbstractRuleBase.java:1107)
at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.removeRule(AbstractRuleBase.java:1085)
at org.drools.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.removeRule(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:208)
    ...
```

Apparently this issue has been worked upon in earlier releases of drools.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad .. something was wrong with my application.
I'm still on 5.4.0.Final, and since I started Logging rule names in the knowledge builder every time I add new rule, the NPE has vanished!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the only difference is logging the name of the rules, that doesn't necessarily point to a bug in your app. It might be some sort of a race condition, and it's not the logging itself that helps rather the delaying caused by doing extra work (logging). If I were you I'd try to track it down and understand what's going on.

Comment: May be. I will look into this. 
I have also observed that it's a specific scenario that causes this. 

When I create the session after I add rules to knowledge base, it works fine - without exceptions.
When I create session first (stateful, of course) and then add rules to knowledge base, it crashes.

Comment: I was facing the same exception, It is resolved by removing static keyword from the methods and variables. I hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try 5.5.1-SNAPSHOT, they changed the rule removal algorithm quite a bit (it is now iterative, used to be recursive). This might have fixed the problem.

Edit: is **not** in 5.5.0.Final, it is only in 5.5.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: 5.5.0.Final is also giving the NPE :(
though at a different line number: 252